# tmux fails to start in babun

Tags: cygwin, tmux, mintty

I am trying to get tmux to work in [babun](https://babun.github.io/). This basically means I am running zsh, oh-my-zsh, mintty and cygwin on Windows (64-bit Windows 7). Babun comes with a package manager, pact, that I used to install tmux. According to [this](http://www.oresteluci.com/unix-terminal-in-windows-with-babun-and-tmux/) guide that should allow me to run tmux, but it fails to load and gives me

> open terminal failed: not a terminal

Since the guide and some others got this to work I am thinking there is something wrong with my configuration. Unfortunately I have not been able to find what exactly. Does anyone know where I might start looking for answers? I'm still relatively new to the Unix philosophy, so I could be missing something trivial.